# Expanding variables into Jekyll Front-End

Tags: yaml, jekyll

It is possible to expand a variable into a post Front-Matter?

I use a series of items for links into my template, like:

```
related_links:
    - text: foo
      link: bar
```

But sometimes I need to refer to other posts into my site. Normally I would use just `/bar` into link, but this is also used as shownotes into a podcast, I want to expand the link for `http://example.com/bar`. But using `{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}` results into:

```
 Error: could not read file [REDACTED]: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 33 column 12
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more elegant at my own:

```
{% assign real_link=link.link %}
{% assign link_start = real_link | slice: 0 %}
{% if  link_start == "/" %}{% assign real_link = real_link | prepend: site.url %}{% endif %}
```

As I start al my locak links with a `/` to warrant that the link will be related with the root in the site, that was a better way for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
related_links:
    - text: foo
      link: {% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}
```

you will get an error because the `{` will start a flow style mapping and `%` cannot start a token in YAML. You have to put the whole scalar in (double) quotes:

```
related_links:
    - text: foo
      link: "{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}"
```

Comment: But by using this, I receive the literal `{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}`in the link. What I want is to make Jekyll parse and obtain the link. By put the scalar into double quotes, it expands to `example.com/posts/baz/`{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do does not work because of Jekyll's pipeline:

1. parse YAML front matter
2. process rest of document with Liquid
3. parse result of previous step with Markdown

`{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}` is a Liquid command. As you see, Liquid processes just the part of your file below the YAML front matter. Therefore, no Liquid replacement takes place there.

You can instead write something like this below the front matter:

```
{% assign link = post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}
```

And then use `{{link}}` elsewhere. If you have multiple links, things get hacky. Something like this *might* work, but I am not enough of a Liquid user to know for sure:

```
{% capture nl %}
{% endcapture %}
{% capture rawlinks %}
{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}
{% post_url YYYY-MM-DD-bar %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign links = rawlinks | split nl %}
```

You can then specify indexes in your YAML front matter:

```
related_links:
  - text: foo
    linkindex: 0
```

And finally, somewhere in your document:

```
{{ links[related_link.linkindex] }}
```

YMMV if this level of uglyness is justified for your use-case.

Comment: This {{link}}  workaround works even at the Front Matter... If this works, this will be a good solution.